# How to delete referenced data using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have two schemas as below.

MirFile Schema

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema

 // Creating a Schema for uploaded files
   const MirFileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
     },
    name: {
     type: String,
     required: [true, "Uploaded file must have a name"],
   },
    image:{
    type:String
   },
    belongsTo:{
      type:ObjectId,
      ref:"MirFolder"
     }
   });

const File = mongoose.model("MirFile", MirFileSchema);

   MirFileSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    MirSubFile.remove({belongsTo: this._id}).exec();
     next();
    });

  module.exports = File;
```

MirSubFileSchema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema

// Creating a Schema for uploaded subfiles
const MirSubFileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  createdAt: {
     type: Date,
     default: Date.now,
   },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Uploaded file must have a text"],
     },
  image:{
     type:String
   },
  belongsTo:{
    type:ObjectId,
    ref:"MirFile"
      }
  });

 const File = mongoose.model("MirSubFile", MirSubFileSchema);
 module.exports = File;
```

When I delete MirFile the document from MirSubFile which holds the _id of MirFile in belongsTo field must be deleted.I have used prehook but its not working.Any guide.?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add your own **'deleteOne'** or '**remove**' Mongoose [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) on the MirFileSchema to deleteOne or remove all other documents

```
exports.DeleteMirFileSchema = (req, res) => {
      MirFileSchema.deleteOne({ _id: req.query._id }, { new: true }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          let errorKeyArray = Object.keys(err.errors);
          let msgArray = errorKeyArray.map((obj) => {
            return err.errors[obj];
          });
          ResponseObj.errorResponse(res, { status: 400, msg: msgArray.join(", ") });
        } else ResponseObj.successResponse(res, data);
      });
    };
```